# Inviting a consumer to Azure AD B2C with custom in-app attributes

Tags: azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Inviting a consumer user to Azure AD B2C has been covered by other Stack Overflow questions & answers, and AFAIK requires the use of custom policies that entail a signed JWT being created and used during invite redemption.

**What I'm trying to figure out:** In our application, we have differently permissioned user groups and different organisations managed by internal RBAC logic. We identify & authorize users based on their `oid` claim in the access token that's returned to `msal-react`/`msal-browser` and used to authenticate against our backend's API.

In Microsoft Graph, a user can be invited and the API will respond with the created user's `oid`. However, this is the wrong type of user and not appropriate for B2C scenarios.

With the custom policy route not creating the user object in AAD B2C at the time of invite, and therefore without knowing the user's `oid` at the time of inviting them to the application, what might be the best way to configure their in-app profile and have them identifiable to the application itself upon first login?

My thought at the moment is to have the application store the emails of users that are invited who have not yet redeemed/signed-in. We can configure the `emails` claim to be returned upon login, which is checked against the invited emails store when an `oid` claim is returned that isn't present in the database. This can then trigger a function to update the user's internal id with the `oid` in their first login's claim.

If this is inadvisable or if there's a better way, I'd be very grateful to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work, or just pre create the user up front via MS Graph API. Then you have an email and objectId available.

You could also put an extension attribute on the account indicating whether the user has redeemed their invite. That would allow you to monitor who has redeemed, and also be a way to provide a different experience depending on if the user has redeemed or not redeemed the link.